# Attempt to read property "Nombre" on bool

Tags: php, html, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to make a show view with Laravel 8 but i can't show the detail, this is the code from the controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $accesorios=DB::table('accesorio as acc')
    ->join('detalle_aparato as da','acc.idAccesorio','=','da.idAccesorio')
    ->select('acc.Nombre')
    ->where('da.idAparato','=',$id);
    return view("almacen.aparato.show",["accesorio"=>Accesorio::findOrFail($id)]);
}
```

And this is the code from the view:

```
@foreach ($accesorio as $acc)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $acc->Nombre}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E86an.png)

When I use:

```
@foreach ($accesorio as $acc)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $acc}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

It prints: 1 for each record

Hope you can help me

Comment: Where do you set `$accesorio`?

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the error message as text instead of an image. Text can be searched.

Answer (score 1):

In you're controller you're using `DB::Table` to set the `$accesorios` variable, but never using it.

You then are setting `accesorio` in your view to `Accesorio::findOrFail($id)` which will only return one instance of the object.

Either pass `$accessorios` into your view

```
return view("almacen.aparato.show",["accesorios"=>$accessorios]);
```

then loop through it

```
@foreach ($accesorios as $acc)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $acc->Nombre}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

or since you're just sending one instance of the object to the view, remove the loop and you can render it like this.

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $accesorio->Nombre }}</td>
</tr>
```